# Как удалить символ перехода на новую строку из VBS скрипта?

Tags: totalcommander

На просторах интернета нашел vbs script.
Он копирует из Total Commander полный путь к файлу в буфер обмена в формате notepad++
Попробовал все работает.
Чтобы скрипт работал, нужно установить компоненту Script Helper ActiveX for TC beta12
http://wincmd.ru/plugring/script_helper.html
Затем Скрипт поместить в 1.vbs файл.
Файл скрипт можно перетащить на панель инструментов Total commander
Затем устанавливаем фокус на нужный нам файл.
Жмем иконку на панели инструментов TC скрипт отрабатывает.
И у нас в буфере содержится полный путь к файлу в формате npp
Проблема, что в конце содержится символ перехода на новую строку.

```
Option Explicit 'https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement
Dim List, Cnt, Buf, CurDir, FullName
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 
' ***********************************************************
Dim TCS
   Set TCS = CreateObject("TCScript.Helper")
   
   TCS.SendCommand "cm_CopyFullNamesToClip"
CurDir = TCS.GetSrcPath 
TCS.SendCommand "cm_CopyFullNamesToClip", True 
'MsgBox  CurDir 

'MsgBox TCS.GetTextFromClip 
FullName = TCS.GetTextFromClip 
FullName = "file:///" + FullName
FullName = Replace(FullName,"\","/")
FullName = Replace(FullName,vbCrLf,"")
'FullName = Replace(FullName,vbCr,"")
MsgBox FullName
WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /c echo " & FullName & " | clip", 0, TRUE

WScript.Quit
```

Помогите поправить скрипт, чтобы удалить этот символ.
Пробовал следующие способы

```
FullName = Replace(FullName,vbCrLf,"")
FullName = Replace(FullName,vbCr,"")
```

Но они не помогли.

Comment: `FullName = Replace(FullName,vbNewLine,"")`? *в конце содержится символ перехода на новую строку.* А ежели в байтах, то что именно?

Comment: Данная команда тоже не помогла. Подскажите, а как посмотреть в байтах? Содержимое буфера поместил в текстовый файл. Файл сохранил сразу. Открыл файл шестнадцатеричным редактором.  http://i7.5cm.ru/i/cUf3.jpg

Comment: а теперь вставь в 16ричный редактор без сохранения в файл. блокнот сам добавляет конец строки .

Comment: такой результат получился http://i7.5cm.ru/i/lHGS.jpg . По моему тоже самое получилось. Скопировал в буфер с помощью скрипта результат и сразу в ставил в HxD

Comment: Ну тогда попробуй влоб: `FullName = Replace(FullName,CHR(13) & CHR(10),"")`.

Comment: все равно не помогает. Я написал в cmd следующую команду . echo 1 | clip . И как выяснилось это именно она добавляет символ перехода на новую строку. Получается не в том месте пытаемся удалить символ. Но как удалить в нужном месте не понятно? Загуглил и сразу нашлось решение. Вот такая команда echo | set /p="Тестируем вывод команды" | clip . Спасибо вам что помогли разобраться.

Comment: Мда.. Ну и извращение же... Посмотри, в какой строке копирование и пойми, что в имени файла и так нет перевода строки, так что никакие замены не помогут.